# To use ng-model for the dynamically created HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have dynamically created the div elements in that there is an element for the button, so I want to use its value through the ng-model, but the value is not coming.

My code is:

```
var url = "/api/chatBot/chatBot";
$http.post(url,data)
.success(function(data){
    $scope.messageToShow = data.messageText;
    $scope.forButtons = data.actions;
    console.log("Message ::", $scope.messageToShow);
    console.log("actions ::", $scope.forButtons[1].value);
    var x='';
    for(var i = 0 ; i<data.actions.length; i++) {
        x= x + "<a ng-model = 'buttons' class = 'btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-xs btn-rounded pull-right' value ="+$scope.forButtons[i].value+" ng-click = 'submitForButton()'>"+$scope.forButtons[i].text+"</a>"
    }
    var newEle = angular.element("<div class='message' ><a class='message-author' ng-model='author'> Bot </a>\
    <span class='message-content' ng-model='messageContent'>"+$scope.messageToShow+"\
    "+x+"</span> </div><br />");
    var target = document.getElementById('messageDiv');
    var temp = $compile(newEle)($scope);
    angular.element(target).append(temp);
    $scope.message = "";
}) .error(function(){
    console.log("ERROR in bot controller");
})


}
```

So when I am doing

```
console.log($scope.buttons) // its coming undefined.
```

So where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: for `ng-model` -- Are you sure that value is hardcoded? and where do you have declare `buttons`?

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<a>` tags or `<span>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should to declare `$scope.buttons = ''`previously at your controler, after that, you can use it as a ng-model

also you can try with `ng-value ="+$scope.forButtons[i].value+"`